# Messed up CSV file

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I was trying to open a CSV file that was in an APK, but the text came up all messed up. I don't know if this is an encoding issue, an encryption or to do with the fact that I changed the .apk file extension to .zip in order to unzip the APK. It's not a very big CSV so the contents are pasted below:

]Ѐ꤀Û጑⚈䷓⹆鎶珑윅꽡ɣ오쑎笞䣳軌��䠜�琩∯흯㍓อ೉졠난រ뎤纫䂆掰➟�뗐㍘澊맭燼暅势욢샫渚欸鱗Ԉ든﷤欳䖟㩴灝ꦞ먯⾧朽獆펮뙕₵㝻㭯鍽쾴겸뺃䀃堩ꗊ⬬䙴䃘ꀴퟷ䘑ཪ뱻捴텍뎙በஆ箆죐�粂琮㭕ꉌ揍좠彩樠≗�Ẹ犓缙祉ᗂ靗᛿Ȿ큸躚嫽䊸ᱱ᷂⾠⍛笼杨᤬㑦譥錏쫾䎽텏认獾뉡撻쟧搓㎙삨Î쪶킐뵆ﺗ䷞˰㼖龌萪曛눣⏪⺕�ﳖ滬刨꼩ħᨿሩ匿錣졪㕮ᒋ䷓ᢆ솙➩竐農퐘뒗焰๐ǚ鷩⫻ᢿ⢲︧䋝잛ⷱ┦٘㾯쁈빞톥ѻ덨ꈾ㨴孑蚎늫楺ꦈ䵙몛鈙㒃鄾髓꾝撋鑲ꠌ⬙ሊﳜ彈橩ﯫ⑦显䶏呸эﮓ혰枂厛虠䉸榒傳ʒ혨ᓈ�釭친屨�蠼�鱩ᇇ쾰ఁ瞼滶ꂷ毤雊ヱ蝧蒹肒㗤蚕ᐈᫌ遑暑䎝໖죒戠韏㋺軚嶕褵⎭㡿㛛ᡎ᎘䔦�읪ᎌ蘨骎ႡჍ뿁쇎龸합눂駐�萑诇㏒嬿擭��ꏮ㪤퓹䟆䖾榲엻鱼᫶燌絕磨봢멖㷩�Ӹ㢲㚟⚝ㄼ⢟哗䦹칇ഃ漦煀Ǭ땘ꬎ蜜榷쒿邷㰞跡ྀ焒뭩鈧귅믓婛담뜜뇟ჰ킠导襌숑㨰丏반ᆗڂ⏁⮋㸳褧쬕䪋口껽瘟쌴夜�ﺻ禭莴砚⡻퍞嫾톇悁풥叛鴳偆湏㞉ṩ㏢魠뢊輲䓵馄稹覆䋓湥咘币ͯ䏶샭䄘ﳝ㝙ầ⿾܆鼫劝䖖쳗肫䆵狮廘뮟ᦼ嬸⨪쒥牵还℉ㄠź㻽׸ᝲ⻬慼쇍앂䓭鞰褏鐐遷，�㟄Ωꃇ舒䯾蝎쑞䋽僋㝰ᧅ唓㠲숱퍵冫覆⯰ᗹ쀛๒⥛﷤�爏≀析秄犑﹄逎⊄ᆍྲྀ䄂䐚ꬱ펨羑ቐ㫼冣瓎圶옟⻴ᐍ쵱⌽买얭瘰峾퉸鰵攴깛諓〩琈璘↠ꬵﷳ�듰舏㡓䓎ế⦮쬗쁢색끃홙핉ꠕᥗ鲘ਆ阔㙁㍐얩ཆ듁ޟ긹傿諅☁쭶辂藳퓰➡驮깔컒輘穱곢褕᭛ᛨᜒ㝖駝롲珮睗꠱၉鱨辅鏞��謻晋鴒�锾੺헹ጦ䯿컚ꃆ죌沕巭睉뇣뇆ớ䕒쥌楄ᱳ咖�皼㌝ଉ執앣⎊⨍醙ᒨ窆損䗟ꝰ휤凋큡鶺ꘈꢩ䬩寝儋冡绹࿛䵉䭕ἂ矦�치펁✣誐䏲홭鶭왰ﰈ齶獃荑൏ꊆꔃ輺욦蘼궶闏᫺⻴�囎쑞砄㱤柘蔲秺즣ⲓ飥ᮦ튰꼓녍㉼걷≵뉚୘嶀䱨᰼띔⶚傊艴魿阭랱篺ᾉ҈ⵝ㧹↛꘷磜旅隦◈�₲ꗮ煉⸎闬뇩뀚ဲꓬὴ窎廻ጼ袒�ʨ痤খ昶扂偶䩫뒷帜騈퀟巛挬⏕෷컘기損ग़⼾춶䪄䔕劎ﭐ냌㹵ʱ鴈鼸ൡ�힫磔ꨥ愣歙띒塣⇄諊ࠅ긂䲷Я첥忉톔⟀ꦔ퐫쑥픆ឡꌭ썮뽹孔콵ⳍⷩ퉃Ⲵ緭ꄇ焹ݐẽ뉦䃒᎙祈䐆⋣唐謡뾟褳渺멅は濮ǐḦ춋蓠ࡩ髂掲눪䡐掶櫲焔굟斚Ȑ숒Ƴ율값挓徔殢覌흩䳺뭐䴙淿娄벁裭ᣱ嫳ỮЗ꿛ᄂȯⶌ芪叡廰竱�揯樱ǣ錈ื툸餏몮㝠ᵞ䝑䩄ਖ첶꽺�㤅䑚꒢⧕⏍喤鰓塶뺌둸氂└″婉䄙쳺ᩋશ팅᳴ೀ퉼닏㱬Ḑᘔऒ䛁簤军踱㥳턩㫻튧晨㶷隵䢪㉑멖왺땀㩞⿲猔겕ḽ⳶閊﷫꽔䳁訰�쇴퇇᜻렕⵺葐䣏옆ḅ담셤ᤸᔷ廒᷶㿐ሦ懄㽍셴뒢਻賵㭶멚ⵥ뤔볇㪰츷䃞吡逤쇤초鍧痧ᓸ먁ᨭᝒ飑⸔鵍隨캥岵㛺ﶮ꣔퀞䒱ሔҐ욣⿥鵼ݜ鿑䯹햬袘ᱎᮒ땠ʁ猼࣋卫㤰罌垸ᛀ뽨ﱨ뎏勺憪돢㋉㻛㕂処몼メ讇㫨튵泩※鉞竮苎௪봮禤�춒쮑챀꧷Ꮧ䴽뎼欿荹�ﺼ꧑嬪ꉌㅀ雌鵌鮮䶞扬⇾�杜�3瘧ᢆ鿝䟧�븏鹢Ꝩ迎뙊悳鰆嵙㞳�昂菵翠쩂뿏葤䃬댋⪃矮ლ뎇杪↌寧廯䈈ᙀ喣౩Ż村ꓵ㫏絽ⸯ쟺ꛒ曖㒵ᘒ꒣娕໘伃蹿狵徙෽聬涊䌪峞볝ᗚꐞ꫏퓑瓆꯾ໍȷᨐ葮ᕜ뱿䣏ⲗὮ嗪銐왆豿걡ᘮ韛鑇ꩪ–䡫㓹㨇躍�펺醳噦짧껨艂뜣쐅尨ዿ⬂핍韱ᑜ梐ᛄ揭裯쌾想�凂拦힑ﮧ쮖ꝴㄱ蹺ꈠ㠁挈虞�䬷橂Ώ胨歓䰠䮂�ꌭ瘢㇮쾘⢩㉗⩀Ἦ珎眪蒠ﮀ㯑货ࢗ給�의ﱈ兠㠥뗖烸⁵讼�㞃Ǧ喂䜟մᗃ骵刱쏳醒㫌쪓೾魱뉛Ⱗ狽᠃辺㑕ꌙꖤꇤ퓕쇘ꎺ玞锽홙䝵麶ⶈ䌔獳넒넟┧굪糱쭧醔媛芗勑鼥頳⡝╤ꬰ쿼뭑瘨㭸늱ᨆ좵ⱡ๥걿ׁ�鴾첓�︦戶擊앚䃧ຼ쩔ﭷ縞뽺ꗴ䡪跭凼စ庥텦攙ѐ씲ᑳ㥜鵂氞楺恢бύ꠱ﹼ縟蕂츐쏝踚훯Ⲯ̺鎾૎呵࿳莜鮻舃쪆畆뼳깬캆�ᷨ搩轎㓸邞櫧紂真됚⊒䒭逊㜹풉ࢼ⅏켰婉䔯껔ㅰ삢畷䇲캠�࠘麟瑉儮럱ᰣ趏滗싰棫�␌ꤜජ겙廎㿩詡⾅䤡푔븻枌◃檅℈㦤�㫪㠪ⲣ쒮쟙ᢉ⾃刳桾ㆃ뮘辥昢浨墧ⷪໃ詁嚯嫶ꝍ鎾�䯑뼗Ԁ軘㉭퇕奢⟖杝鈿孳ଞ酊ﲻ掁賈᧋趱矍殏瀯ŉ陇焎鞄ᓓ㺷঩⼬朶箰㔮繪弹澢贓ꌼ偘얰웢圅퇚햸ꉵ㆚쀔阛诨Б�唖羑፦됊␄僄黌氛窰ೊ樨倹焰ዩ썞崥浰랙鹁㻫澌燫뾝濵ꚲ傫㶝ۘ䒘殒뇌﹭凥賓历鲽Ԃ칎贋넯鰃ȋङ�㽼㉳擓⵭阑绱譌ꔏ⏯撝⅔ꂆ뚚
䆏쐵ꒄ�맓鎫闧仏˶䋉栐륎谧瘏狩봜꒸줈䷂띇殢帢캀片伔莣幔䕕ᧄᰌ㉔寱䉘䆘ꡰ毟鹝෭抣졧壒ꤌ㻣箣쮧尿Ἆ澹뮱꿦ㄾ蔩䶬남苨⥁ꡦ䇬㒒浽뼻ㆃ郵놊⡉㇮꽴搮⭪놨ᜒ择ᖘ쩮㽹ᇥ쯍㧈갉浥䭂Û㉺⥼⾳衚몷摒�䗆♻ɯ⏔弤⩣⦊젉裿卦䥯퀱譲꽩⢆䲶笽겮祫挤挔蜾闂᷍灲ﴂᘥ唆쥰懱鰧镙焷��ᓂ疆夗횺禮윑逰뱵곣뵧ﱞ菑他欬筠珙ꚩ䱻ꋫ꧓⵹㶭ﺓ䗟렎ል퐧嗿렮臩⦍娷醐ꚻᆗ㊆唒꼟ᓷ㮥罌駢泥⌠鞢볊㞠麾䰹梵䉭⻎퓀萁定쾠鼹砎縇巒뤨䎅��划뿺תּ뚌λ⛲䆒伭灋䀙鱯桮帻豮ྭ㰓싱�巽�쮗圻漈ꠇ柉霞慰볎஽ቚⒼ뾜탾㯡䟱퇛ម휉昞솢腕쓨띓讼똍吳פּ칈꘥錄㒻⥡뫎힂⟢⹷簚䯣讛臿⠯뜒鳼섄䮧ꩽ骖䱍촇Β墆俏ꚓ⦸ꁄ䋒ܹ貐䘈ꋿ냀Ƅ蕴ꌀ哼㆓伫ꕮ紮렗ꥸ熕᫑ꚽ硠짖譳姏髏ៅᓨ볜†矂낆툶Ἑ韝屺꽎폱쩽㞷ࡻﾬ抟㷟拈䕞௷꯯ഩ蕥蚺㴎퍪剕띴覵뀻搐쭳㎥끯룠䵠때ꕜ䨨ꛆ폭ꯪۗ氶ꝭӷ㢓⧨噖愈집ᷬ齇봿嚓凒㭽⣈�臾ฤ떱솶뇆ꂲ䂀�쐨鷋鴙컚뺄꺺韉ぅ⡕趦d赁쓺﷨齅㕗�羶댉়榐ɹ隌麟䙬帊볼ꭃ旦ᷲ᣹㍵�얳壽堽㬡ꅛⴄ㊚꼚퓜橎뚿줛풊ꕯ⸍라묺寬犾셺꽰뱌㈑꺰맟寤氂뇤莜逑䎢匏플ώ铄萧뺴梔힄솼畴⁼齗鷅蕔⇊饥嵖鰢�㵴䢐䨏甽䩪机멮㽻᥆㖹糓놉镘틵㜇纯ᜥ賑卥课磖넲壗䃌ꩻ꫻⇧풨㮟ꎞ狎됔䶸릕ﯻ⚂鶼臠춊菏ᪧ즵ᢊ濧뉨ξ饥璝๺ﰌ짔뽩楈⇰獏ᰦ苟礒쾐쟿喉ᘳ煔Ꟈ䖗ￏܧ㌹伢结퇇ሐ밪璒偛ꈌ줋鄞쳋녻䏟﮼ߛ醱䵼⹱媞鶢싵㳜褏Ʃ㬔羒᪘帍㦽니㜏陕똌뗶븷颻ﾊオ筊囀챩ᚇꀸꭂꙈᝉ㐭⿵ᛸ╢��䀌脗�暝젨맸힁䘤歩趠ꊇ講᫨鑯Ꝯ讁๯裙ᬭ絓䄈蠼ꓸ豍ꁂ�䑽乫徢㜒令ﰽ῀ﵜ縑㑒詭廉朠䌩銠솽⛙碏�࿸뮇邉뢄싎෽솩趞㏢῁ꪰ�帼慐봚㌩螱焃殺徏Ჯ儩点ﲍ쾊挊큓덮݃ⱸၩቨﰈ㢏物鐪嬟䷄솽坏㐦ꪐ凙汘ᬌ沴靫◒н㧐昖ᗊ멃槠荆�冱퀵耐ꯆ䆶브볒咤ک蝿갟湾틯炛⾫䁁䯙웏琖릥氅렳㷿鳵솚釘範垛ⱞ쫼ⳃ爹ṭ뱯䂕⠔頪븞熁芺ኵ忭᠒쟃㖧ꗦ픣껧�슻ᴁ兾뙥諤਻筮簪༃羘浟ᖾ랩櫒콌⢼ї儕ﻠ详䣋式琼┿ꚳ貌᷉駏켍㞟궸ᛴȯ罟㒿馫᭜喗�ń�⅋蒷㸻厬敱칂笯놾鐲ก㒻᧶Å펪뻣⹼韌佞೫榐닧诐珐ⵏ됵䥞ー뛆⊹鴑�巭齐⳿㙮䁢㋀撧쩟뮡◐ꉎ↸襰�୞렇౧頩俈ⵎ봥譿ᘴ复溉윙쩞ޅ⪎鴍᤽즦牢妘脴쒐ݨΊ㟲�鴩䯌嚤᝴燎눢槑韹醫똗䍸ⴘ軼刎ﱪ龤䗕玅灷眴씍ꦓⷫ嘁哾ຟ蒓쪁ᅼ봄鼪뭞鰚᫩뮘똈晣•劯趬㻰쫥Ḽ㉲詍�癝栧請리�⽒썱둺荎씇�ଆၙ迵癣座冁僗霾靪誇鐫渓욑趩冷ᷗ堃斷ᒲ똀ꨊ껬牰ಆ勍⛍첎ᐹ栙ﭱ㓭툘끝창施蛃ᮖ뉋䯔㖼锭ﴬ淚⦊᥆壞樜川椤ꗠ⇗歉쀱놆꜍�凲흓鬺吿⿕棂岄ⶑ㥈秔鳧뒉ⳃ坑၀绫慓髲뛘ꚬ˧쪣뮾橢阘떪쯜ﺁ姨뜢ꔠ⃿뾃ఈ퐮堁펗࿛㌑눑꼜弿辠⻍㠌⨒⿰穩恖ɩᬈ嗐㇧踉궕ⱒ런ຎ菏혏슨꿌�妝⇠䘽箁ꤷ꺑┙꛲樏졁샇槎❟诰梥퓌Ꮗヸ翲睧쭩줖ᢕ㭉ﲝ왃␃ኾ窸珌⭿㮚늱聼蓩보䉲⟌輒๱቞᭚꘧೎ދꥵ颉⭒㩘袃闉릜佉뾅薭붙淬輤䠘襈걤釭ጙ㞷⒢榅籔傊轩ꐾ晦臡鯏饢뽛廾莶﹏ծ詥䈖㣁펊ᰪ숢紩Ⅎ㬎킈ꂭ놤ﯯ橢䱒ힶ¼ᷓ粂ᆱ㦂⣰Ὴ�⸢焙䊤�ᱭ鱱浫Ě㭝꾋왶ኩ냨ⶴ삟웬乵歲ퟒ巜ᓍࣕ쳂㩧리朥僉ꅚ䳸㸕恎砊隆儧桍㢹딇㼭潓ꞎ踠�뭇쯙큫볼뚘ᵾف욑롶ᩝ縉탐몱攊姡�誥膽种☓뫰톒긪滩ᗟ⑪讣䮿봉㈺鑗᪍慿붼静髜�졚杮ᛗ搒ᔻ觪疭�褯⒘粗답삫뾁蹞䍆䝸끯쓢䂳稅讕睏竳蛟廪᱑渰ᜇ듀馜䪴㊶泷춤킋慒ఄ緷脶鷅̟啘≷찅缝븉�쬡ᄉ畨᠕걍恤䘙縆핀蟿涛ຽ࿆쟻ᡜ䫤땻⪕沯谱ᆆ㥢玩ආ绺Ꮪ눕쭒돇顷ै�凅㋓᭨짔븸띉埥檛䍼㕷嗐ꌹ쯊혦ࢯ苹쁼銅⟻꼉땏徱佲ɿ㠲낻׾잽겪ᐣ鿞뎈㵼唧룡䪺䡆엎礈�쓜�썖蓯헳ほ骈儔�傥�銻詶献㺝ᴓ욳頊整簚訪謏冗玄鷭ﴧ첂᎜彩麩Ȼ궛ሳ蔫駷䘟ꋶ킌엻⨮㎻�⊁匦唽ꉣ왰백퇴뻎媿縉튢�ෞ睔枤ⳅ簉둫經䓔ᛰ㸚�訐๥믻ᔏ䳧걟ﹼ툚햡ꉫ쓒憤ʽ껕뱾驷ᒹ㧝㯔繲陕眉催巍뻿䔑꿑ꆼ좢筧ꤛ䬦축␇⧉ࡂ�ũ㶔䔷ꮮ냅௄꺟擂䒵㮛ᑺ灀⁤䝒볭퍖Ⓐ브蘱壀ꖣ獧輛넿岲௑젰拷᫇䪥ᠮ嬙펎稖⼉ㄎ⧚ɏ⏺㗀剦騫栔톇㯖蘕烥㹪쉾䎫ᜪ秄튻䫀鈥ꊊ徭瞎쿗⩹띔멎熒紽禪姏檅ꄠዄ闾鮁䓨꒚돢㤈䄵膨ꃰ꾓捒厫녊㾆ᒸ㜝摦『❠䕩㙭䓟ꍈ瞦㼶�障∘䄒ס꒯쮡掆ᕷᙜ멗诞䀎䙞풠Ꮛ멻絁វ엦뽞ᇅ楇死顠쟏鸘㐧㢑㼈鍒겶ⷣ⸑䉼㏦ឨᡧ䍏췎ꌸக揅㥉靕䩷苕쥇䴮ਝ遠홍鹯ὢጋ煲뜯ႂ틔뻵缭宰缬批둳㨠眆邈赆뎃橦⋼퍎៭䲄㒫頥ᱟ�ꯛ㒞䤧⳰ꜹ䆠쳰灴袣�鬀ꦁ䮏�筳興폦튠ⶖ波賓艹휺성䒠Ӌ롄Ȇ﷬뽁㑸밃㧹᪫㻯⇞癒ڧ⏮몛갌ି褞ᝪ읝쯢�抿혃泒ો�블왹㰷帠韍瓕礪䧾룱辢⿮䲃蒶曳སⷭ鑳౳䰤廓斋ꪂ냬Ԡ嬃鞜荝쨳櫿⣱麴�饣ৱ䤗⩺ꟺ갟⪜䝟⵩잒쉸孺䱵�䮌ᧄ癲�┭࣪뛳쪤舚鑛퍡糓鯎鬛쓾ဢ媑鉓刔旖管퉹铌흵ퟐ㉖쐇د䑬♈Ċ剞⎧鴂닛赨삞ㄓ꯳젫࢜〽䃠࿢幵郜嫡ﾚ䉱ⷺ膤揋ꉅਗ妦闍᣽ࡦ叾赓ూ䯀둰�훇茺䢮긄॑侽흵ﺦ⵱홮㉸客꺵郞↬陶퍸⬋裒쌏蠓⸉퓵�鐻墔Ꮋ㟡Ḷ❰肒욶綽䅎漵╝☾߃㯡雟虣숗즇涠萇ن︰닕쨙偉빩牱酭贬콎ᤈ㲃ㅙ秡⵱ଂ讜웾姶鯞⥁㲮┴Ǫ뮎☢勂⢔쉽௄﮾⳻첋෾藀廁䏗᱿袘솶훣⍙▷솝ᅟ폔◜䠰⽚挃邅웋뮅쥓ᣂ캥盶鎰फ庌Ⓠ遯ﭘ樑畒뒕夗洿蘡ꐀ疀⑫楁驆楬坕闵骳ꗘ疒븟ᴦ䗟霵踆鄵躈滍≑ޖ梋䘕쐼ꌥಽ霕䀨牤䘝ᡒᙢ竑쀀쨼Ж⏸휎깬Ć裏躆熸⊱亾ⅸ赇怸䝖釔勡ҋ㎋伂⟎ፘ騵̠쎖釁괍⤄プ୘쎈鄗똸脞⎾鈀ബ栆Öៈ捓㼥௭쉳혛萁顯⁼椲j┻㴦㗎�ᥭ꾾핦㈊碤⒄ͻ፨筗鬷Ꞔ絴忩邹矲ꞡ᳡姸衖ٮꙃ뷷퐞璙䋲ꑿድ刘팫륒傰䧷஍븶놎並諘戮兔㶿飉꧊៤죟䂊啡韁蜲쐉�话嗜ꍃ蘬샘⛫◴ꋸ涳䮯뗛쮔洫⩿玚鮍临嫍ᛳ⳵덛൯灨킓♕픽䧰ꉷ法ꀲ䥁䠇婞剓瀑俑袄慄姅蛪ॾ팦礱섶壶﷖㯿揚雋⮫⏿꿮셋䱡䁉᜾廬캔㊯ڙ綁펖헆遤㈯䢘ﳍ疾뙌Ⳑ趄圁䁌仼⋘殼Ṁ읃㐥앸쯤盆榿캐뜟驅駢땟꿱蕏죑�㦤낾┖⧴陷콣覛鷼✈䶔럮㫟蚵⦕糪撯⦨�饸쏟安댷ḯﱚ৶�

I don't have Excel installed on my computer so I couldn't do anything to the file on it. CSV files also don't open on Excel Online. I would really appreciate if anyone could find a way to fix this so I could do the same to 55 other CSV files (from the same APK) having the same problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are not using Excel, what does the Excel tag have to do with anything?  How did you open the CSV?  Which encodings did you try and fal?

Answer (score 0):

APK is the extension for Android app. I don't it can contain CSV files. Even if it does, the content is for the Android app only.

The only thing you can do is to change the file extension from APK into CSV and see if it works.

Comment: The CSV file is within one of the folders in the APK file. The whole APK is obviously not a CSV.